# jQuery giving reference error when adding an Enum through Razor

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, enums

Here is my code. On click of the button I am trying to enter an enum flag value in to a database table, but I am getting a reference error.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default clean" data-id="@item.RoomId">status</button>
```

```
$(function () {
  $('.clean').click(function () {
    $.post("@Url.Action("SetStatus", "ReceptionHk")", { 
      id: $(this).data("id"), 
      newStatus: @EnumHkStatus.Cleaning 
    });
  });
});
```

```csharp
[Flags]
public enum EnumHkStatus
{
  None,
  Repair,
  Cleaning,
  InventoryCheck,
  Occupied
};
```

on click of the button i am trying to enter value in the status column as int value as it is in the enumerator with flags but i am getting following error

> ReferenceError: Cleaning is not defined

Please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at what your server-side code is outputting to the browser.  It sounds like this:

```
@EnumHkStatus.Cleaning
```

is outputting this:

```
Cleaning
```

Which isn't understood by the JavaScript code.  (That's what the error is specifically telling you.)  For your JavaScript code you'd probably either want that to be a string:

```
'@EnumHkStatus.Cleaning'
```

or an int:

```
@((int)EnumHkStatus.Cleaning)
```

(Which one is up to you.  You may want to test both, I'm not sure if the model binder can automatically translate either or both of them back to the `enum` value.)  So that ultimately your POST call would at least contain valid code.  For example:

```
$.post("@Url.Action("SetStatus", "ReceptionHk")", { id: $(this).data("id"), newStatus: @((int)EnumHkStatus.Cleaning) });
```

would output something like:

```
$.post("/ReceptionHk/SetStatus", { id: $(this).data("id"), newStatus: 3 });
```

You *might* then need to update your `SetStatus` action to accept an `int` or `string` (whichever you chose), unless the model binding can convert to the corresponding `enum` for you.  You'll want to test that.  If you do need to change the method signature, just convert it back to the corresponding `enum` at the start of the action method.

Side note: You *probably* want to have some code to handle the AJAX response, if for no other reason than to check the success/failure of the operation.